# angular debug issure "about:blank"

Tags: angular, debugging

Im using Iteliji Idea. When I try to debug angular application I have browser with about:blank url. I tried to use Chrome and Edge and result the same. nodejs v15. os win10. What should I do?

[message in intiji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwp3I.png)

i tried this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9216840190226-Angular-debugging-doesn-t-work-Chrome-opens-about-blank- but this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"--remote-allow-origins=*" to chrome options helped me

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60002/Blank-page-opened-aboutblank-when-debugging-JS-PHP-in-Chrome-using-custom-data-or-not

Answer (score 5):

*Ctrl+Alt+S -> Tools -> Web Browsers and Preview*

Select your browser, then click 'Edit' icon and insert into *command line options*

```
--remote-allow-origins=*
```

works for me.

Also to avoid any potential errors I have chosen Edge for debugging.

Comment: Edge also gave me this issue, but it's based on chrome so the above command line option works for it as well.